# Mapping a long long integer to vector of pairs

Tags: c++, c++14, unordered-map

In C++14 , I am trying to use map to store values that I need to access very quickly.

Actually the problem is

- I need to map `long long int` to vectors but it should hold 2 values.
- I think vector of pairs is suitable for this.

Example :
5 be my `long long int`

For 5 ->   I have

```
         1,3

         2,5

         5,4
```

For 89998  I have

```
        6,899

        8,8887

        9999,566
```

etc

`unordered_map<long long,vector<pair<int,int>>>mp`

But I don't know how to access it and traverse it

Questions

1.How do I add those values to map

2.How do I access it. Example if possible*

Comment: Generally, a question like "is it possible to do ..." can always be answered as "yes". Same thing here, it's very possible to do it.

Comment: Please answer 2nd one dude

Comment: As for the syntax, remember that the map `mp` has an overloaded "index" operator, which return a reference to the value for a specific key. So e.g. `mp[5]` could be used as a vector, which you can iterate/traverse (`for (auto const& pair : mp[5]) { std::cout << pair.first << " - " << pair.second << '\n'; }`), or add elements to (`mp[5].emplace_back(1, 3);`)

Comment: What is your problem? For accessing, use, e.g., an indexing `operator[]`. For traversing, use, e.g., iterators or range-based for loop. These are very standard ways mentioned in every beginners C++ book.

Comment: U are traversing the vector also right??Because its little confusing@Someprogrammerdude

Comment: ["please help" is not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). You can turn it into a good answerable quesiton if you show your code that attempts to access and traverse it, explain what it is supposed to do and how it is not doing what it should, including possible errors, input and output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your actual issue is that you don't know how to use `std::unordered_map` regardless of your use case.

The first thing you should have done is to read the [related documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) about `std::unordered_map`. It would have bring you the answer to all of your questions.

---

> How do I add those values to map ?

You have several (C++14) ways of doing so:

- `std::unordered_map::insert()`
- `std::unordered_map::emplace()`
- `std::unordered_map::operator[]()`

<sub>**Note:** These functions **are not the same**. It is up to you to read the documentation about the details of each function (what it does and how to use it).</sub>

> How do I access it ?

You can access elements using:

- `std::unordered_map::operator[]()` (**note:** Will insert element if it does not exist)
- `std::unordered_map::at()` (**note:** Will throw an `std::out_of_range` exception if it does not exist)

> But I don't know how to access it and traverse it.

If you want to traverse it, the easiest way is to use a [range-based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for).

---

**Example:**

```
int main()
{
    using ValueType = std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>;

    // Create the map
    std::unordered_map<long long, ValueType> umap;

    // Fill the map
    umap.emplace(std::make_pair<long long, ValueType>(5,     {{1,   3}, {2,    5}, {5,      4}}));
    umap.emplace(std::make_pair<long long, ValueType>(89998, {{6, 899}, {8, 8887}, {9999, 556}}));

    // Iterate over the map
    for(const std::pair<long long, ValueType> & element : umap)
    {
        std::cout << element.first << " -> " << '[';
        for(const std::pair<int, int> & couple : element.second)
            std::cout << '(' << couple.first << ", " << couple.second << ')';
        std::cout << "]\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> ```
> 89998 -> [(6, 899)(8, 8887)(9999, 556)]
> 5 -> [(1, 3)(2, 5)(5, 4)]
> ```

[Live example (C++14)](https://godbolt.org/z/HLY7FT)

Comment: Thank you very much.
This is the answer I was searching for.